# VBA: Convert from local drive name to network drive name

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have this macro that initially only used by me. But I need to distribute it to other people now. Basically, I wrote a macro that let you browse for file, and then it will convert my local path into network drive path (HTML style). As you can see from my code below, I am specifically referring to R drive and Z drive. However, if other people use it, they could have A drive and B drive instead. How do I rewrite the following such that, it will pull the network drive instead of local drive? Thanks!

```
Private Sub GetFilePath_Click()

FilePath = Application.GetOpenFilename()
If FilePath <> False Then
    Range("E6").Value = FilePath
End If

End Sub
```

A function that convert the file that selected into HTML path

```
Function ModFilePath(FilePath As String) As String

Dim HTMLFilePath As String
Dim Drive1 As String
Dim Drive2 As String
Dim Drive3 As String

On Error Resume Next

HTMLFilePath = Replace(FilePath, " ", "%20")

'I know somehow I need to rewrite this part
Drive1 = Replace(HTMLFilePath, "R:\", "\\network_name\apple\")
Drive2 = Replace(HTMLFilePath, "Z:\", "\\network_name\orange\")

If Err.Number = 0 Then
    If Left(HTMLFilePath, 1) = "R" Then
        ModFilePath = Drive1
    Else
        If Left(HTMLFilePath, 1) = "Z" Then
            ModFilePath = Drive2
        End If
    End If

Else
    ModFilePath = "Error"
End If

End Function
```

Comment: [How To Get UNC Path From a Mapped Network Share's Drive Letter](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/192689)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research, I actually answered my own question. Here is the code for those who are interested. The following code gets the UNC path instead of the network share drive letter when the end users import their file:

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function SetCurrentDirectory _
Lib "kernel32" _
Alias "SetCurrentDirectoryA" ( _
ByVal lpPathName As String) _
As Long

Public Sub GetFilePath_Click()
Dim vFileToOpen As Variant
Dim strCurDir As String
Dim WikiName As String

'// Keep Original Dir
strCurDir = CurDir

'// Note: If the UNC path does not exist then
'// It will default to your current one
SetCurrentDirectory "\\network_name\"
vFileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename
If TypeName(vFileToOpen) <> "Boolean" Then
    Range("E6").Value = vFileToOpen
End If


'// End by resetting to last/original Dir
ChDir strCurDir

End Sub
```

The function below convert the file path that the imported file to HTML style.

```
Function Path2UNC(sFullName As String) As String
    ' Converts the mapped drive path in sFullName to a UNC path if one exists.
    ' If not, returns a null string

    Dim sDrive      As String
    Dim i           As Long
    Dim ModDrive1 As String

    Application.Volatile

    sDrive = UCase(Left(sFullName, 2))

    With CreateObject("WScript.Network").EnumNetworkDrives
        For i = 0 To .Count - 1 Step 2
            If .Item(i) = sDrive Then
                Path2UNC = .Item(i + 1) & Mid(sFullName, 3)
                Exit For
             End If
        Next
     End With

     ModDrive1 = Replace(Path2UNC, " ", "%20")
     Path2UNC = ModDrive1

 End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would add Inputbox to let ppl type their drive and the value given concatenated with rest of the path.

Answer (score 0):

Copied from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/160529

**Microsoft Office 97 and Microsoft Office 7.0**

```
   ' 32-bit Function version.
   ' Enter this declaration on a single line.
   Declare Function WNetGetConnection32 Lib "MPR.DLL" Alias _
      "WNetGetConnectionA" (ByVal lpszLocalName As String, ByVal _
      lpszRemoteName As String, lSize As Long) As Long

   ' 32-bit declarations:
   Dim lpszRemoteName As String
   Dim lSize As Long

   ' Use for the return value of WNetGetConnection() API.
   Const NO_ERROR As Long = 0

   ' The size used for the string buffer. Adjust this if you
   ' need a larger buffer.
   Const lBUFFER_SIZE As Long = 255

   Sub GetNetPath()

      ' Prompt the user to type the mapped drive letter.
      DriveLetter = UCase(InputBox("Enter Drive Letter of Your Network" & _
         "Connection." & Chr(10) & "i.e. F (do not enter a colon)"))

      ' Add a colon to the drive letter entered.
      DriveLetter = DriveLetter & ":"

      ' Specifies the size in characters of the buffer.
      cbRemoteName = lBUFFER_SIZE

      ' Prepare a string variable by padding spaces.
      lpszRemoteName = lpszRemoteName & Space(lBUFFER_SIZE)

      ' Return the UNC path (\\Server\Share).
      lStatus& = WNetGetConnection32(DriveLetter, lpszRemoteName, _
         cbRemoteName)

      ' Verify that the WNetGetConnection() succeeded. WNetGetConnection()
      ' returns 0 (NO_ERROR) if it successfully retrieves the UNC path.
      If lStatus& = NO_ERROR Then

         ' Display the UNC path.
          MsgBox lpszRemoteName, vbInformation

      Else
         ' Unable to obtain the UNC path.
         MsgBox "Unable to obtain the UNC path.", vbInformation
      End If

   End Sub
```

**Microsoft Excel 5.0**

```
   ' 16-bit Function for Excel 5.0.    ' Enter this declaration on a single line.    Declare Function WNetGetConnection Lib "user" (ByVal lpszLocalName _
      As String, ByVal lpszRemoteName As String, cbRemoteName As _
      Integer) As Integer

   ' 16-bit declarations:    Dim NetName As String    Dim x As Integer Dim DriveLetter As String

   Sub GetNetPath()

      ' Prompt the user to type the mapped drive letter.
      DriveLetter = UCase(InputBox("Enter Drive Letter of Your Network" & _
         "Connection." & Chr(10) & "i.e. F (do not enter a colon)"))

      DriveLetter = DriveLetter & ":"

      ' 16-bit call for Excel 5.0.
      ' Pad NetName with spaces.
      NetName = NetName & Space(80)

      ' API call returns one of eight values. If it returns zero, it is
      ' successful.
      x = WNetGetConnection(DriveLetter, NetName, 80)

      ' Display the UNC path.
      MsgBox NetName

   End Sub
```